# DJStripe sends receipt email even if setting is False

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Recently I implemented payments on my Django site using the awesome djstripe app. I didn't want it to send its custom receipt emails but rather use the ones Stripe itself provides.

There's a setting for preventing that behaviour (as per the [documentation](http://dj-stripe.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#djstripe-send-invoice-receipt-emails-true), you have to set DJSTRIPE_SEND_INVOICE_RECEIPT_EMAILS to False to make it happen), but even if I did it, the djstripe email is sent.

My djstripe settings:

```
#DjStripe
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = get_key("STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY")
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = get_key("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY")
DJSTRIPE_SEND_INVOICE_RECEIPT_EMAILS = False
DJSTRIPE_CURRENCIES = [('eur', 'Euro')]
```

This is pretty strange. Has anyone encountered the same problem (and hopefully has a way around it)?

Comment: It looks to me like you are using the settings correctly. It might be worth stepping through the code to see where the email is sent, and creating an issue on [the project page](https://github.com/pydanny/dj-stripe).

Comment: I looked at the repo and it seems that this setting only refers to Invoice receipts. There are other receipts the are not controlled by this setting (such as Charge receipts, etc.)

Comment: Are these DJStripe email receipts or Stripe receipts? Stripe receipts are controlled by your account settings in your Stripe dashboard

Comment: @mfcovington: you were right, that setting is referred to Invoices and not Charges. After a bit of search through the code, I found that in order to disable the email, you have to pass send_receipt=False to the Customer.charge method.